# /varible int time won't display the numeric value entered

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

```
//varible int time won't display the numeric value entered
```

The Speed of Sound
The following table shows the approximate speed of sound in air, water, and steel:
Medium Speed
Air 1,100 feet per second
Water 4,900 feet per second
Steel 16,400 feet per second
Write a program that asks the user to enter “air”, “water”, or “steel”, and the distance that 
a sound wave will travel in the medium. The program should then display the amount of 
time it will take. You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in air with 
the following formula:
Time 5 Distance / 1,100
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in water with the following formula:
Time 5 Distance / 4,900
You can calculate the amount of time it takes sound to travel in steel with the following formula:
Time 5 Distance / 16,400

[C:\Users\DeLaCruz\Desktop\j2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33T0K.png)

[V:\CSC106-Spring 2016\j3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gELHB.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramSpeedOfSound{

public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;


    System.out.println("Enter Air, water or steel ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();

if(input.equals("Air")){


System.out.println("what is the Distance? ");
int Distance = keyboard.nextInt();
int var = 1100;
double time = Distance / var;

System.out.println("it would take " + time);

}
else if(input.equals("Water")){


System.out.println("what is the Distance? ");
int Distance = keyboard.nextInt();

    double time = (((Distance/ 4900)));

System.out.println("it would take " + time);
}
else{

System.out.println("what is the Distance? ");


    int Distance = keyboard.nextInt();

    double time = Distance/ 16400;

System.out.println("it would take " + time);

    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure the strings you are comparing to are also in all uppercase. E.g. change `Air` to `AIR` and `Water` to `WATER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to typecast either a denominator or numerator to float when dividing two integers. The reason you're getting 0.0 as answer is because division of two integers gives integer value as 0 which is later converted to double 0.0. For example see line 3 in the code below. You can also typecast to double.

```
        System.out.println("what is the Distance? ");
        int Distance = keyboard.nextInt();
        double time = (float)Distance / 16400;
        System.out.println("it would take " + time);
```

Below is the output after typecasting Distance to float

```
        Enter Air, water or steel 
        Air
        what is the Distance? 
        100
        it would take 0.006097560748457909
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`.

In your program, the control would not enter any of the conditional blocks if the value of `input` is not entered in the format you are checking.

Your code will not work for:

- WATER, AIR, water etc.

So use `equalsIgnoreCase()` to avoid case sentivity.

Note:

Make the following correction:

```
Double Distance=keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Division of the type integer/integer may lead to loss in precision when the dividend is not completely divisible by the divisor.

- 5/3 will return 1 and you will lose the decimal part.
- 3/5 will return 0.

So it's better to declare `Distance` as `Double` instead of `int`.